# openshift, rest apis binary deployment

Tags: rest, openshift

I was following the link
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Enterprise/2/pdf/REST_API_Guide/OpenShift_Enterprise-2-REST_API_Guide-en-US.pdf 
to build my rest api java application that will deploy a WAR binary file from a web location into my account.

I am getting

InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/application/#{myAppID}/deployments, status=422, reason=Unprocessable Entity}} as a response:

where #{myAppID} is the app uuid that I replace here for security

I am using glassfish rest api and my piece of code is:

```
    String url_of_war = "https://code.google.com/p/web-actions/downloads/detail?name=helloworld.war";
    WebTarget webtarget;
    Client client
    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
    return true;
    }
    };
    client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(trustAllCertificates()).hostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier ).build();
    }
    URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();
    try {
      uriBuilder = uriBuilder.setScheme("https").setHost("openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/").setPath("application/#{myAppId}/deployments");
      if (getPort() > 0) {
        uriBuilder = uriBuilder.setPort(getPort());
      }
      URI uri = uriBuilder.build();
      webtarget = client.target(uri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      String msg = "Could not build URI!";
      throw new RuntimeException(msg, e);
    }
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webtarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    invocationBuilder.header("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.encodeBase64String("#{myuser}:#{mypass}".getBytes()));
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("hot_deploy", "false");
    form.param("force_clean_build", "false");
    form.param("artifact_url", URLEncoder.encode(url_of_war, "UTF-8"));
    Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.form(form));
```

what am I doing wrong here, I am stuck in this since 30 days with no clue online, i also tried to create openshift/jboss compatible deployment folder where i placed the war file and made available for download as a copmressed .tar.gz file but same problem
your help is highly appreciated.
thank you

Comment: a correction, the war url I used is: String url_of_war = "https://web-actions.googlecode.com/files/helloworld.war";

Answer (score 0):

Binary deployments need to be in a very specific format, they can't just be a war file (or a zipped war file).

You should check out this blog article (https://blog.openshift.com/using-openshift-without-git/) about using binary deployments on OpenShift Online for further reference.  I think it will help you get your code working.

Comment: thank you for your reply, actually this is one of the things that i tried, i created a deployment folder structure as this website mentions and put the war inside as ROOT.war in the specific folder and tar gz the folder, exactly as i do when i manually deploy from rhc, so the resulting binary file is deployable manually, i made it available from my own website as downloadable lonk, that i tested, but yet it did not work